# Is a windows allowed filename secure for Injections? (SQL , JavaScript etc.)

Tags: windows, security, sql-injection, filenames, code-injection

I would like to ask if a windows allowed filename is secure for SQL (Oracle and general), JS, xml, etc injections.

The following characters are checked and replaced: /:*?"<>| (also with their ascii values etc). 
Also the length could not be more than ~180 characters

The checks are made securely, both in client (only for usability) and server side (for security)

The filename is saved to an oracle DB and it has a flow like oracle->java->xml->xslt->browser to be displayed.

EDIT: @Bohemian 's answer points out the insecure part of SQL injection (which could simply be prohibited with the use of prepared statements). **How about JS or xml injection?** (That could lead to XSS or access to hdd through xslt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't safe. Because windows allows the single quote `'` and the semi colon `;` in file names.
That combination is all you need to inject SQL:

SQL injection example (in java):

```
int userid = 999;
String filename = "foo';delete from users;update users set name = 'bar";
String sql = "update users set avatar = '" + filename + "' where id = " + userid;
System.out.println(sql);
```

Output:

```
update users set avatar = 'foo';delete from users;update users set name = 'bar' where id = 999
```

This is valid, and pernicious, SQL.

---

Windows also allows both curly `{}` and square `[]` brackets in filenames. I can't think of an example right now, but it seems that a javascript injection would be possible too, perhaps if passed to `eval()`. (Perhaps someone could provide a working example - feel free to edit one in here)

Comment: Simple and complete answer. Thanks :)

Comment: On thing is missing, lets say there is prepare statement used (so the system is secure from sql injections), could you locate a JS injection?

Comment: Wouldn't the same logic apply to JS injection? eg if you passed your filename through `eval()` you could pretty much do anything

Comment: There would be needed something like for example:  </div> <script> </script> , so from my point of view it seems safe, that is why I ask.. The filename of course does not pass from eval().. but it could be in html attribute (where an other vulnerability is located)

Comment: I've updated the question to add that `{}[]` are also allowed in filenames, which could allow a way in. I can't think of an example though - JS isn't my strong suit. I could think of one if you didn't mask off the double quote, because that would allow a json object to be compromised in a way similar to the SQL example.

Comment: Just a picky remark: If you delete all users, you won’t be able to update them.

Comment: @Gumbo yes you will be able to update them: the update will work, but no rows will be affected (because there aren't any). The point here is that the injected SQL could do nearly anything. The update at the end is just there to make the whole SQL sequence syntactically valid, otherwise the syntax error may cause the whole lot to be rolled back, defeating the evil effect.